# PowerPoint Add-in only works after the third initialization on Office Online

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, officedev

## Context

---

In my company, I am in charge of developing an Add-in of type Content App only for PowerPoint.
**The add-in** is built with ASP.NET MVC (4.5) and AngularJS (1.6.8) and **works seamlessly on PowerPoint client** (Version 1811, Build 11029.20079).

**Tests procedure**
Windows 10 64-bits
Chrome, v70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Adblocker disabled

**Manifest used**
This manifest passed the validation tool (https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-validator).

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ContentApp">
  <Id>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>My Company</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Office Add-in name" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Office Add-in description." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://my-company.com/PluginLogo32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://my-company.com/PluginLogo64.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://my-company.com/support/" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>my-company.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Settings" />
    </Sets>
    <Methods>
      <Method Name="Settings.get" />
      <Method Name="Settings.set" />
      <Method Name="Settings.remove" />
      <Method Name="Settings.saveAsync" />
    </Methods>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://my-company.com/plugin" />
    <RequestedWidth>800</RequestedWidth>
    <RequestedHeight>600</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <AllowSnapshot>true</AllowSnapshot>
</OfficeApp>
```

**Office initialization used**

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var init = function () {
        App.tags = @Html.Raw(WorkContext.ActivPortalUserEntity.GetUserTagsAsJson());
        App.languages = @Html.Raw(LocalizationManager.GetPortalJsonScript());
        App.AP_URL = '@WorkContext.Uri';
        App.V_KEY_FORM = '@AntiforgeryHelper.GetTokenName()';
        App.V_VALUE_FORM = '@AntiforgeryHelper.GetToken()';
        App.LabelURLSuffix = '';
        App.URLSuffix = '@Model.TemplateDocument.URLSuffix';
        App.IsDefaultUser = @Json.Encode(WorkContext.ActivPortalUserEntity.IsDefaultUser);
        App.DashboardParametersQueryString = '@Html.Raw(Model.RenderContext.Request.GetParametersAsQuerystring())';
        App.DashboardFilters = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RenderContext.Request.GlobalCriteriaObjects));
        App.ZoomFilters = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RenderContext.Request.GlobalCriteriaIndexes));
        App.WebPartFormatUseCorner = true;
        App.DeportedToggleView = true;
        App.ToggleViewMode = 'accordion';
        App.searchPlaceHolderText = "@Resource("L_appSearchPlaceHolder_Text", "Portal")";
        App.viewType = '';
        App.documentRepository = '@ApplicationConfigService.ActivPortalServerConfig.DocumentsRepository';
        App.WPAllowIconsHide = false;
        App.Language = '@WorkContext.UserLanguage';
        App.searchURL = [];
        App.EditMode = false;
        App.EditContentMode = false;
        App.CATALOG_PROXY = '@WorkContext.Uri' + 'Portal/CatalogProvider';
        App.RENDER_URL = '@WorkContext.Uri' + 'Portal/Render';
        App.CHOICE_PROXY = '@WorkContext.Uri' + 'Portal/Render/TemplateRequest';
        App.POST_TEMPLATE_PROXY = '@WorkContext.Uri' + 'Portal/Render/TemplateRequest';
        App.moduleScripts = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GetPageScripts()));
        App.moduleStylesSheets = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GetPageStyles()));
        App.angularClientContext = @Html.Raw(@Html.GetJsonClientContext());

        App.scriptDebug = (typeof App.scriptDebug == undefined) ? false : App.scriptDebug;
        App.ScriptsManager = new Activportal.UI.Resources({ scriptDebug: App.scriptDebug });
        App.StylesManager = new Activportal.UI.Resources();

        //Localization
        MinimizeTip_Text = "@Resource("L_Minimize_Text", "Portal")";
        ExpandTip_Text = "@Resource("L_Maximize_Text", "Portal")";
        ErrorUpdatingPart_Text = "@Resource("L_InvalidURL_Text", "Portal")";
        ConfirmRemoveGlobalFilter_Text = "@Resource("L_ConfirmRemoveGlobalFilter_Text", "Portal")";
        WaitMessage_Text = "@Resource("L_WaitMessage_Text", "Portal")";
        SessionEnd_Text = "@Resource("L_SessionEndMessage_Text", "Portal")";

        window.addEvent('domready', function () {
            App.isDashboardLoaded();
            App.Start();
        });
    };

    try {
        if (Office) {
            Office.initialize = init;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Office.js is missing.");
            if (!window.external.GetContext) {
                init();
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
</script>
```

## Problem

---

Just to repeat myself, The **Add-in works seamlessly on PowerPoint 2016 client** (see above for version).
However, in **PowerPoint Online** I struggle on an **issue**: the **initialization** of the add-in.

1. When inserting the Add-in or reloading the login page is displayed with an opacity as follow: [image: Add-in initialization]
2. Then after 2 seconds this message appears: "Sorry...We could not start the Add-in because we encountered a problem. Try later or contact your system administrator." [image: Add-in initialization error message]
    The only message I get from the console are the followings: [image]
3. At this point, i count 1 initialization. When I click on “DÉMARRER” the same thing happens (second init). And then, when I click again (third init). The Add-in finally works like on PowerPoint client.
   Here is what is look like when the login page works.
   https://imgur.com/F9QNvvg

So, on Office Online, it’s only the third initialization, the Add-in it works.
I noticed approximately the same behavior for all major browser in their last version.

## Question

---

**Is there something I am missing?**
I am open to any suggestions, I didn't find any solution on this particular matter.

Comment: Take a look at the "Fiddler trace" or network tab of the built-in browser debugger to see if there are particular calls being made from the browser that are failing (and what the responses are).  The console message didn't seem too telling.

Comment: @BrianClink Roger that. I'll check those and report the result.

Comment: Could you translate the error message? Also what do you mean with an opacity, is it an overlay or is something transparant? Or is it an overlay like when you debug with some devtools.

Comment: Well, regarding the traces, it is not as easy as planned. As soon, I enabled the tracer (Fiddler), Office tells me it can't reach the domain of the Add-in. Once I disabled it, i have the usual error with the initialization and after 3 init, everything is working.

Comment: @Fluous Added translation to the post. During initialization, it looks like an overlay is added on top of the add-in area when loading.

Comment: Could you also add the Javascript that is being called in the initialization function.

Comment: @Fluous Added init code to the post.

Answer (score 2):

**What I did to fix this issue**
Well, my mistake has been to not understand well how Office.js works.

In my login page
 - I added the script Office.js.
 - I initialize the script.

```
if (Office) {
   if (Office.context === undefined) {
      Office.onReady(function () { });
   }
}
```

In my main page
 - I change the way to initialize the script.

```
if (Office) {
   if (Office.context === undefined) {
      Office.onReady(function () { });
   }
}
```

**Conclusion**
It seems Office.js must be present in the first page of the application. And in every pages which use Office API.

In addition, It is better to Use Office.onReady() instead of Office.initialize().

Things to note:

- I had to contact Microsoft to found out this solution.
   Documentation not that abvious, perhaps?
- I still have some error in console but i can use the Add-in and the API without problem.